# Passing a block to a Moose method

Tags: perl, moose

Is it somehow possible to pass blocks to Moose methods? In standard Perl, I can define a function with prototypes like this

```
sub fn (&) {
    my $code =\&{shift @_};
    $code->();
}
```

and then pass a block to the function without explicit `sub` references, i.e. `fn { say "Hi there, world" }`.

I think this is only possible if the subroutine is the first parameter, and as this is always `$self` with a Moose method, it doesn't seem possible there, forcing me to do it the slightly more explicit way:

```
sub wrapper {
    my ($self, $code) = @_;
    $code->()
}

Wrapper->wrapper(sub { say "Hi there, world" });
```

Now this would be a pretty convenient way to wrap some blocks, i.e. to provide some additional text or conditionally execute code or wrap an eval around some code where the error handling stays the same (e.g. eval some code and log errors, record user etc.).

If I'm not missing something, is there some semi-convenient workaround or alternative method to achieve something like this without too much line noise?

Comment: Yup, that's it. With OO-style calling, prototypes don't get used.

Comment: One could cut down two characters with `sub l(&){return shift}`, then `Wrapper->wrapper(l{say "Howdy"})`. This isn't really worth it.

Comment: as per amon, but usually I name the sub with the & prototype something appropriate like 'cb' for callback or 'then', and either bless into a package directly (with bless) or pass it to a constructor of a class, so that Moose can validate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [`PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlX%3a%3aMethodCallWithBlock) CPAN module which contorts the Perl syntax (via the [`Devel::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aDeclare) module) to allow you to put a *block* after a method call.

For e.g.:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock;

{
    package Foo;
    use Moose;

    sub bar {
        my ($self, $code) = @_;
        $code->();
    }
}

Foo->bar { say "Hi there world" };
```

This module was released as a *proof of concept*.  So far I've had no issues with it but YMMV.

Comment: And i heard that that Switch.pm was a cool way to do switch/ /case in Perl.

Comment: For others reading, MkV is digging at Switch.pm's use of source filters which try to parse and modify your entire source file as a string. The inevitable mistakes parsing Perl can cause bizarre side effects all over your code. Devel::Declare is a whole other ball game. DD hooks into the Perl parser to find the points it wants to modify. In fact, extra hooks have been added to Perl recently for DD to use. While not perfect, it's pretty stable and has none of the class of bugs that source filters did. Apples and oranges.